# C macro defining prefixed macro with condition

Tags: c++, c, macros

I wrote a logging mechanism with several log levels.

```
LOG_FATAL(s)
LOG_ERROR(s)
LOG_WARN(s)
...
```

Now I want to be able to activate or deactivate the logging for some modules.
What I do now:

```
#ifdef MOUDLE_LOG_ON
  MODULE_LOG_FATAL(s)  LOG_FATAL(s) 
  MODULE_LOG_ERROR(s)  LOG_ERROR(s)
  MODULE_LOG_WARN(s)   LOG_WARN(s)
  ...
#else
  MODULE_LOG_FATAL(s) 
  MODULE_LOG_ERROR(s)
  MODULE_LOG_WARN(s)
  ...
#endif
```

Is there a way to place the prefixing in a macro to use it like this:

```
SETUPLOGGING(MODULE)
```

Comment: I guess that this does not even compile. perhaps a `#define`  would not go amiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering if using macros and inline functions could solve your issue:

```
void inline LOG_FATAL(const char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

#define SETUPLOGGING(x) \
    void inline x ## _LOG_FATAL(const char *s) { LOG_FATAL(s); }

SETUPLOGGING(MODULE)

int main()
{
    MODULE_LOG_FATAL("hello");
}
```

After preprocessing, this produces:

```
void inline LOG_FATAL(const char *s)
{
 printf("%s\n", s);
}

void inline MODULE_LOG_FATAL(const char *s) { LOG_FATAL(s); }

int main()
{
 MODULE_LOG_FATAL("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Macros can't define new macros. And when defining a macro, it isn't possible to build its name from other macro, so you can't use the common work around of including a file which defines what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro to define which include file you were going to use, but then, why not use an include file and use the macro in there?